# R: How to pass a list of selection expressions (strings in this case) to the subset function?

Tags: r, subset, logical-operators

Here is some example data:

```
data = data.frame(series = c("1a", "1b", "1e"), reading = c(0.1, 0.4, 0.6))

> data
  series reading
1     1a     0.1
2     1b     0.4
3     1e     0.6
```

Which I can pull out selective single rows using subset:

```
> subset (data, series == "1a")
  series reading
1     1a     0.1
```

And pull out multiple rows using a logical OR

```
> subset (data, series == "1a" | series  == "1e")
  series reading
1     1a     0.1
3     1e     0.6
```

But if I have a long list of series expressions, this gets really annoying to input, so I'd prefer to define them in a better way, something like this:

```
series_you_want = c("1a", "1e")  (although even this sucks a little)
```

and be able to do something like this,

```
subset (data, series == series_you_want)
```

The above obviously fails, I'm just not sure what the best way to do this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the `%in%` operator

```
> dat <- data.frame(series = c("1a", "1b", "1e"), reading = c(0.1, 0.4, 0.6))
> series_you_want <- c("1a", "1e")
> subset(dat, series %in% series_you_want)
```

Comment: Thanks, RCS, that works great, I also added this to make listing the series easier.

series_you_want = "1a,1b,1e"


series_you_want_list = unlist(strsplit(series_you_want, ","))