# how to pass an expression through a function for the subset function to evaluate in R

Tags: r, subset

i'm trying to write a subset method for a different object class that i'd like users to be able to execute the same way they use the `subset.data.frame` function.  i've read a few related articles like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880906/pass-subset-argument-through-a-function-to-subset) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609647/r-how-to-pass-a-list-of-selection-expressions-strings-in-this-case-to-the-sub), but i don't think they're the solution here.  i believe i'm using the wrong environment, but i don't understand enough about environments and also the `substitute` function to figure out why the first half of this code works but the second half doesn't.  could anyone explain what i'm doing wrong below and then how to make a working `lsubset` function that could take `gear == 4` as its second parameter?  sorry if my searches missed a similar question..  thanks!!

```
# create a list of mtcars data frames
mtlist <- list( mtcars , mtcars , mtcars )
# subset them all - this works
lapply( mtlist , subset , gear == 4 )


# create a function that simply replicates the task above
lsubset <- 
    function( x , sset ){
        lapply( x , subset , sset )
    }

# this does not work for some reason
lsubset( mtlist , gear == 4 )
```

Comment: I'd take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset) question thread and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850141/programming-safe-version-of-subset-to-evaluate-its-condition-while-called-from/12850252#12850252).  It is commonly said that using `subset` programatically is a bad idea, and I think you're about to discover why!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about:

```
lsubset <- 
    function( x , ... ){
        lapply( x , subset , ... )
    }

lsubset( mtlist , gear == 4 )
```

Comment: Kudos to me for resisting the urge to end my answer with "This has been a work of R"

Comment: The trick here is that `gear==4` is passed down to `subset` unevaluated, am I right?

Comment: That was my understanding but I'm no programmer.