# Pass an expression into a nested function call

Tags: r

I want to wrap a function which takes an expression as its argument.

For example:

```
f <- function(expr1) {
    substitute(expr1)
}
f({Sys.time()})
```

The result will be

```
>f({Sys.time()})
{
    Sys.time()
}
```

However, if I wrap a function `g` over `f`:

```
g <- function(expr2) {
    f(expr2)
}
```

Then the result becomes

```
>g({Sys.time()})
expr2
```

What should I do to make the wrapped result unchanged?

Thanks.

Comment: Same question but this has a better title: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407852/how-to-pass-an-expression-through-a-function-for-the-subset-function-to-evaluate/17407998#17407998

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
g <- function(...) {
    f(...)
}

## > g({Sys.time()})
## {
##     Sys.time()
## }
```